# layoutifneeded does not trigger layoutSubviews

Tags: ios, swift

So, I have code like this

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = self.hideNavBar
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
//    view.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

But when I call this code using `view.layoutIfNeeded()`, the main view's layoutSubview function is not called at all

But if I call `view.setNeedsLayout()` instead, the layoutSubview function is called and all the constraints are upadted.

shouldn't `view.setNeedsLayout` & `view.layoutIfNeeded` should both call layoutSubview functions? Just that their timing is a bit different?

Comment: I believe both functions schedule a layout update for the next layout cycle. Maybe `.layoutIfNeeded()` decided a layout update is not needed... ‍♂️

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I believe layoutIfNeeded doesnt schedule, but calls the update immediately (it is said to be layoutsubViews, but apparently not in this case). Also, what condition would there be such that layoutIfNeeded is ignored? Cuz even if there is nothing to update, but when I call view.setNeedsLayout(), the layoutSubView function is still called

Comment: @progammingBeignner As I know, `setNeedsLayout` -> `layoutSubview` -> `layoutIfNeeded` it's the way everything happens. Seem like `layoutIfNeeded` is final step and of course, it won't call `layoutSubview`

Comment: @trungduc I don think so... We can refer to http://tech.gc.com/demystifying-ios-layout/ for some info ... but layoutIfNeeded definitely comes before layoutSubviews

Comment: @progammingBeignner I'm not sure that post is totally right. You can check it easily by creating a custom view, set a breakpoint inside `setNeedsLayout`, `layoutSubview`, `layoutIfNeeded` and see what happen.

Answer (score 2):

The `layoutIfNeeded` method, as the name says, lays out **immediately** but only if there are "invalidated" views. The `setNeedsLayout`, instead, "invalidate" the view, but it will be layed out on the next update cycle.

Calling (first `setNeedsLayout` and then `layoutIfNeeded`) ensure that the view is invalidated and re-layout immediately.

### From documentation:

- [setNeedsLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622601-setneedslayout)
- [layoutIfNeeded](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded)